# Memory profiling embedded python

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I would like to do some memory profiling on a python module that is called in an embedded fashion (from C++). There is some suspicion that parts of it are considerably less than optimal, but it is a fairly complicated module, making manual inspection quite cumbersome. I can change the python code if needed (e.g. to add @profile function decorators etc). Ideally I would like to profile certain functions within these modules.

I have been looking at a few options, e.g. memory_profiler, but I cannot figure out how to get these to work in an embedded fashion (they work fine when testing on stand-alone scripts).
The question is if anyone knows of a way to approach this problem.

I understand this question is perhaps somewhat vague, but a wider search online did not really come up with any concrete strategies on how to approach this. Even so, I expect this to be an issue that may be relevant to more people.

Answer (score 2):

I was too hasty when asking this question. The concerns I addressed (i.e. memory_profiler not being able to do this) were premature. Our code actually redirects the output somewhere else - and it's all there.

In short - the following works perfectly well (as also explained in the memory_profiler docs):

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def your_function(...):
```

and a nice line-by-line memory report will be shown.
I apologise for the premature question - and can wholeheartedly recommend memory_profiler for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution