# Python memory explosion with embedded functions

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have used Python for a while and from time to time I meet some memory explosion problem. I have searched for some sources to resolve my question such as 
[Memory profiling embedded python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171792/memory-profiling-embedded-python)
and
https://mflerackers.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/fixing-and-avoiding-memory-leaks-in-python/
and
[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**del**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) However, none of them works for me.

My current problem is the memory explosion when using embedded functions. The following codes works fine:

```
class A:
  def fa:
    some operations
    get dictionary1
    combine dictionary1 to get string1
    dictionary1 = None
    return *string1*

  def fb: 
    for i in range(0, j):
      call self.fa
      get dictionary2 by processing *string1* 
      # dictionary1 and dictionary2 are basically the same. 
      update *dictionary3* by processing dictionary2
      dictionary2 = None
    return *dictionary3*

class B:
  def ga: 
    for n in range(0, m):
      call A.fb # as one argument is updated dynamically, I have to call it within the loop 
      processes *dictoinary3*
    return something
```

The problem arouses when I notice that I don't need to combine *dictionary1* to *string1*, I can directly pass *dictionary1* to A.fb. I implemented it this way, then the program becomes extremely slow and the memory usage explodes for more than 10 times. I have verified that both method returned correct result.

May anybody suggest why such a little modification will result in so large difference?

Previously, I also noticed this when I was levelizing nodes in a multi-source tree (with 100,000+ nodes). If I start levelizing from the source node (which may have largest height) the memory usage is 100 times worse than that from the source node which may have smallest height. While the levelization time is about the same.

This has baffled me for a long time. Thank you so much in advance!

If anybody interested, I can email you the source code for a more clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you're solving the same problem shouldn't imply anything about the efficiency of the solution. Same issue can be claimed with sorting arrays: you can use bubble-sort `O(n^2)`, or merge-sort `O(nlogn)`, or, if you can apply some restrictions you can use a non-comparison sorting algorithm like radix or bucket-sort which have linear runtime.

Starting to traverse from different nodes will generate different ways of traversing the graph - some of which might be non-efficient (repeating nodes more times).

As for "combine dictionary1 to string1" - it might be a very expensive operation and since this function is called recursively (many times) - the performance could be significantly poorer. But that's just an educated guess and cannot be answered without having more details about the complexity of the operations performed in these functions.

Comment: I completely agree with you based on my educated knowledge on data structure and algorithms. What I don't understand is that by eliminating the combining and then detaching processes, I shall gain improvements either in CPU time or memory usage, however, both of them become worse...

Comment: We can speculate - but it won't be productive. Better try to use a profiler to understand the diff in performance.

Comment: Hi alfasin, I have figured out the reason. Finally it is because after modifying the implementation, some data format is not strictly the same. The program spent a lot of time on distinguishing them. Thanks for reminding me to use profiler!